# Flickering screen of returning Widget, flutter-bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm new to flutter, I just followed the firebase login flutter-bloc tutorial to do the same operation for my app,

Everything goes well, except the first screen loading.

```
home: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is Uninitialized) { <=== return regardless of the state
        return WelcomeScreen();
      } else if (state is Unauthenticated) { <=== return regardless of the state
        return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
      } else if (state is Authenticated) {
        return HomeScreen( <=== return regardless of the state
          user: state.user,
          homeRepository: _homeRepository,
          userRepository: _userRepository,
        );
      }
      return WelcomeScreen();
    },
```

[flutter-bloc main.dart](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login/lib/main.dart)

The if condition return every screen regardless of the state, if state condition met, It should break the condition and return only one widget. But it's not the case here, it returns every screen weird.

[image: The flutter juggling after loading the screen]

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Here is the bloc which controls the flow, here you can apply your custom logic. https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login/lib/authentication_bloc/authentication_bloc.dart

Comment: It is because the initial state of the bloc is `Uninitialized`. And you are returning `WelcomeScreen` for this case. So whenever you run the app it will show you the `WelcomeScreen` initially

Comment: i have added the GIF to see more clearly whats was the problem. The welcomescreen instantly disappear but, i don't know why the screen flickers always in emulator and physical device.

Comment: @EngineSense post your bloc

Comment: @EngineSense ??

Comment: Pardon me! I was busy with other issues. Thanks for reminder will post the code tonight IST.

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause on why the screen flickers is that a new screen is being returned by `BlocBuilder()`. Per docs, [BlocBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) rebuilds in response to new states. To prevent unnecessary rebuilds you're not expecting, you may consider using [BlocListener](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocListener-class.html) as it's guaranteed to be called only once for each `state` change unlike the `builder` in `BlocBuilder`.